# Error 400 while trying to get my Spotify token refreshed

Tags: python, python-requests, spotify

I am trying to refresh my Spotify Access Token by using the refresh token, i followed the spotify documentation and tried finding my answers here but i couldn't find anything that solved my problem.

Here is the code I'm trying to use for refreshing

```
def refresh_the_token():
    auth_client = client_id + ":" + client_secret
    auth_encode = 'Basic ' + base64.b64encode(auth_client.encode()).decode()

    headers = {
        'Authorization': auth_encode,
        'Content - Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }

    data = {
        'grant_type': 'refresh_token',
        'refresh_token': refresh_token
    }

    response = requests.post('https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token', data=data, headers=headers)  # sends request off to spotify

    if response.status_code == 200:  # checks if request was valid
        print("The request to went through we got a status 200; Spotify token refreshed")
        response_json = response.json()
        new_expire = response_json['expires_in']
        print("the time left on new token is: " + str(new_expire / 60) + "min")  # says how long
        return response_json["access_token"]
    else:
        print("ERROR! The response we got was: " + str(response))
```

The error I get:

```
<html>

<head>

<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<title>400 Bad Request</title>

</head>

<body text=#000000 bgcolor=#ffffff>

<h1>Error: Bad Request</h1>
<h2>Your client has issued a malformed or illegal request.</h2>
<h2></h2>

</body>

</html>
```

Here is the spotify documentation about refreshing the token: [Request a refreshed token](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/tutorials/code-flow#request-a-refreshed-access-token)

Comment: why are you decoding it again your auth code?

Comment: I'm not even sure but it errors out if i remove it and when it's still there it outputs base64 so the request should be fine

Answer (score 0):

Using request [Basic Authentication](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/authentication/) makes easy life instead of direct use b64encode.

So this format is correct update token by refresh token.
Also using [Flask session](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-use-flask-session-in-python-flask/#) to save tokens and retrieve tokens.

```js
    res = requests.post(TOKEN_URL,
        auth = HTTPBasicAuth(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET),
        data={
            'grant_type': 'refresh_token',
            'refresh_token': session['refresh_token']
        })
```

##### Demo

Demo will use Flask server framework to get access token and refresh token.
This full code.

```js
from flask import Flask, request, redirect, render_template, session
from flask_session import Session

from requests_oauthlib import OAuth2Session
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
import requests
import json

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SESSION_PERMANENT"] = False
app.config["SESSION_TYPE"] = "filesystem"
Session(app)

AUTH_URL = 'https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize'
TOKEN_URL = 'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token'
PORT = 3000 # replace <your redirect port>
REDIRECT_URI = 'http://localhost:{}/callback'.format(PORT) # my configuration is 'http://localhost:3000/callback' in dashboard
CLIENT_ID   = "<your client ID>"
CLIENT_SECRET = "<your client secret>"

SCOPE = [
    "user-read-email",
    "playlist-read-collaborative"
]

@app.route("/login")
def login():
    spotify = OAuth2Session(CLIENT_ID, scope=SCOPE, redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URI)
    authorization_url, state = spotify.authorization_url(AUTH_URL)
    return redirect(authorization_url)

@app.route("/callback", methods=['GET'])
def callback():
    code = request.args.get('code')
    res = requests.post(TOKEN_URL,
        auth = HTTPBasicAuth(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET),
        data={
            'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
            'code': code,
            'redirect_uri': REDIRECT_URI
        })

    # assign to session
    token_response = res.json()
    session['access_token'] = token_response['access_token']
    session['refresh_token'] = token_response['refresh_token']
    session['expires_in'] = token_response['expires_in']
    session['scope'] = token_response['scope']

    # retrieve from session
    return render_template('index.html', 
        message = 'Get access token and refresh token by authorization_code',
        token = json.dumps({
            'access-token' : session['access_token'],
            'expires_in': session['expires_in'],
            'scope' : session['scope'],
            'refresh_token' : session['refresh_token']
            }, indent = 2))

@app.route("/refresh_token", methods=['GET'])
def refresh_the_token():
    res = requests.post(TOKEN_URL,
        auth = HTTPBasicAuth(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET),
        data={
            'grant_type': 'refresh_token',
            'refresh_token': session['refresh_token']
        })
    # assign to session
    token_response = res.json()
    session['access_token'] = token_response['access_token']
    session['expires_in'] = token_response['expires_in']
    session['scope'] = token_response['scope']

    # retrieve from session
    return render_template('index.html',
        message = 'Update access token by refresh_token',
        token=json.dumps({
            'access-token' : session['access_token'],
            'token_type': 'Bearer',
            'expires_in': session['expires_in'],
            'scope' : session['scope']
        }, indent = 2))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port = PORT,debug = True)
```

This is `templates/index.html`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Spotify Token Demo</title>

    <style>
        div {
            font-size: 1em;
            font-family: serif;
        }
       </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>{{ message }}</h2>
    <div>
        <pre>{{ token }}</pre>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

##### File tree

[image]

##### Run it

```
python app.py
```

##### Get access token by Browser

```
localhost:3000/login
```

[image]

##### Update access token by `refresh_token`

```
localhost:3000/refresh_token
```

[image]